# Внедрение зависимостей в Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity-2, owin

В *базовом* шаблоне при создании `asp.net mvc` проекта в качестве системы авторизации (по умолчанию) используется `asp.net identity`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {}
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {}

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
        IOwinContext context)
    {}
}

public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(
        ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) : 
        base(userManager, authenticationManager) { }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {}

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options,
        IOwinContext context)
    {}
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {}

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {}

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {}
}
```

Указанные выше классы используются при настройки авторизации в приложении

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use
        // a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    }
}
```

Как в приведенном коде избавиться от *сильной зависимости* - `app.CreatePerOwinContext()`?

Comment: а зачем избавляться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуемся IoC контейнером [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/index.html) для внедрения зависимостей.

При помощи менеджера пакетов Nuget установим необходимые пакеты:

- [Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/3.5.2)
- [Autofac ASP.NET MVC 5 Integration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Owin/3.1.0)
- [Autofac OWIN Integration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Owin/3.1.0)

Внесем следующие изменения в класс `Startup`:

```
private void ConfigureContainer(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // STANDARD MVC SETUP:

    // Register your MVC controllers.
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

    // Run other optional steps, like registering model binders,
    // web abstractions, etc., then set the dependency resolver
    // to be Autofac.

    builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        .As<SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
        .As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.Register<IAuthenticationManager>((c, p) => c.Resolve<IOwinContext>()
        .Authentication).InstancePerRequest();

    var dataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
    builder.Register<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>((c, p) =>
        BuildUserManager(c, p, dataProtectionProvider));


    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    // OWIN MVC SETUP:

    // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac MVC middleware.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacMvc();
    }

    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> BuildUserManager(
        IComponentContext context,
        IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters,
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
    {
        var manager =
            new ApplicationUserManager(context.Resolve<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>());
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers.
        // This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code
        // for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code",
            new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code",
            new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });

        //manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        //manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
                dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Добавим вызов метода `ConfigureContainer(IAppBuilder app)` в метод `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureContainer(app);
    }
}
```

После выше приведенных действий можно удалить методы `app.CreatePerOwinContext()` из метода `ConfigureAuth()`

так же необходимо модифицировать `AccountControlle, ManageController`:

1. Убрать конструктор без параметров.
2. Удалить следующие свойства: `UserManager`, `SignInManager`, `AuthenticationManager`

Вот так может выглядеть `AccountController` после внесения необходимых изменений:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> signInManager,
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
    //Прочие необходимые методы
}
```

Использованные источники информации:

- [Autofac’s documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/237773/)

Answer (score 1):

Строка `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` нужна фреймворку для того чтобы можно было получть объект `ApplicationUserManager` в `SecurityStampValidator`.

Не обязательно оставлять код для `ApplicationUserManager.Create` но нужно  научить фреймворк как получать инстанс `ApplicationUserManager`. Если используется DI контейнер, то можно будет заменать на `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());`

Comment: по большому счету в проекте по умолчанию меня устраивало все до тех пор пока я не стал *расслаивать* приложение: т.е. `ApplicationUser` в `DAO`, `ApplicationDbContext` в `DAL`.

Comment: Да, с этим у Identity есть проблемы - там где живет `ApplicationUser` должна быть зависимость от EF что не всегда желаемо.